# Filtering object based on it's other values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

Based on below data I need to filter and map this object to show specific names and `nameOfGame` if `Object.keys` of otherTypes = number from types. I was trying with includes but I am messing something.

```
output: 
[ 
name1: [game1],
name2: [game2, game3]
name3: []
]
```

```
data: {
    types: [{
        nameOfGame: game1
        number: [1]
      },
      {
        nameOfGame: game2
        number: [3]
      },
      {
        nameOfGame: game3
        number: [3]
      }
    ],
    otherTypes: {
      1: {
        name: 'name1'
      }
      3: {
        name: 'name2'
      }
      5: {
        name: 'name3'
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why does `game3` would be associted to `name3` for exemple ?

Comment: @nem0z it's not nameofGames are just random names,  so name and nameofGame are independent. It's about taking keys from otherTypes, check if they contain number's from types and based on that printing nameOfGame.

Comment: You must share the expected output, we cannot understand the probleme if you give an output than doesn't correspond to the given intputs (i.e `data`)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think your input should change to:

```js
var data = {
    types: [{
        nameOfGame: 'game1',
        number: [1]
    },
    {
        nameOfGame: 'game2',
        number: [3]
    },
    {
        nameOfGame: 'game3',
        number: [3]
    }],
    otherTypes: {
        1: { name: 'name1' },
        3: { name: 'name2' },
        5: { name: 'name3' },
    }
};

var output = [];
for (var p in data.otherTypes) {
    var outputItem = {};
    var name = data.otherTypes[p]["name"];
    outputItem[name] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.types.length; i++) {
        if (p === data.types[i].number[0].toString()) {
            outputItem[name].push(data.types[i]["nameOfGame"])
        }
    }
    output.push(outputItem);
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Don't use picture to share code please. You can use `code snippet` to share code then print the result

Comment: that picture is the test result, not code block. @nem0z

Comment: That's why I recommande you to use `code snippet` ;)